# Facebook Graph API - A supposed Missing Permission for the next page in Event Pagination

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

It has been a very long time since I needed to post here (especially for api endpoints) so please excuse me if I am not formatting the issue correctly.

I have been working with the Facebook Graph API (**v17.0**) to simply get the events of my gaming group so that we can filter them for all upcoming events. After a bit of trouble **I got the first 25 working** using my **developer test app** but the **pagination** is where it goes wrong. Below is the endpoint I am using

```
// version (v17.0), group id and accesstoken are all populated in the code/endpoint and work

https://graph.facebook.com/{_version}/{_groupID}/events?access_token={_accessToken}&fields=name,start_time,cover,description,place
```

In the api is the following for paging

```
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": {before value goes here},
      "after": {after value goes here}
    },
    "next": {next value goes here}
  }
```

What is odd is that I could not get the next value to work. It always reports the following issue. **No matter how many of the permissions I add or if I was doing it in C# or the Graph API explorer itself**. I have put the permissions for my **User Access Token** I have below the exception.

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Missing Permission",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "A5s64gZJGBX-DMPGpn5lqsn"
  }
}
```

```
user_events, user_managed_groups, groups_access_member_info, page_events
```

This is telling me I am missing something but the documentation was not helpful and I cannot see anything about this particular outcome. Could anyone help me figure out what is causing this as it has definitely left me defeated in figuring it out. I am happy to answer any questions

Comment: Maybe it is messing up the generation of the "next" URL, because your original URL is malformed already? `/events?access_token={...}&events?fields=name,`

Comment: Possibly. Could you imagine how the original URL should look? I thought this might be correct?

Comment: Should probably be `/events?access_token={...}&fields=name,...` - `&events` in there "on its own" made little sense, the endpoint was specified at the beginning of the path already, and the `fields` as a second GET parameter, should be separated from the previous one by an ampersand.

Comment: Gotcha. I have made the change to be exactly as you mentioned. I can still get the first 25 results but pagination does not work

Comment: What does the next URL it generates for you actually look like?

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/[GROUP ID GOES HERE]/events?access_token=[ACCESS TOKEN GOES HERE]&pretty=0&fields=name%2Cstart_time%2Ccover%2Cdescription%2Cplace&limit=25&after=QVFIUktnVk9JVUtQTHR2dGdsckYxMjIwbUxOYzNoZAlc1b25yNmRudDgweFp0eVNiSWJjM1pyYXpvZAjFPbFVsRU9KQ2c4Y1h6QWpDUnRNYkRtdzhFWUNXZAUl3

This is what it looks like :)

Comment: Looks like your starting URL (plus URL encoding on some values), only with `limit` and `after` parameters added - but no change in what fields you are actually requesting from the endpoint, so it does not make much sense that there should be a permission missing for anything "new". Sounds like a bug to me, I'd create a report if there was nothing similar already: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/